# RecyclerView добавление как удалить\изменить\добавить один пункт списка, не перезагружая список

Tags: android

У меня есть `RecyclerView`. Мне нужно реализовать удаление, изменение и добавление по пункту списка (просто `TextView`). Если с изменением все понятно — просто получаю и изменяю `View`, то как можно удалить и добавить только один пункт, не перезагружая весь список?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавьте/удалите элемент в/из список(-ка) данных, отображаемых адаптером.
2. Вызовите `notifyItemInserted(int positionOfInsertedElement);`/`notifyItemRemoved(int positionOfRemovedElement);` метод адаптера.

Comment: А как его удалить\добавить-то?)

Comment: Э-э-э... Ну... В документации заверяют, что для сего есть методы `add` & `remove`... У классов реализующих `List`...

Comment: А разве `RecyclerView` реализует лист? О.о

Comment: Нет. А вот данные, которые вы в адаптер передаёте, вполне могут. Если у вас массив, то всё сложнее (а по мне так и невозможно почти)

Comment: А если двумерный? :\

Comment: Ну, вроде как можно заменить на `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, например...

Comment: Только в этом механизме фиг разберешься, верно?)

Comment: Эх... Ладно, проще создать 3 `List` и не парить мозги.

Comment: Да нет, всё просто. Вместо `array[x][y]` будет `arrayList.get(x).get(y)`

Comment: Ладно, создам доп. проект и разберусь.

Comment: Перенес программу с `String[][]` на `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` и все заработало (удаление\изменение еще не реализовывал). Только одно подозрительно: после того, как я переписал, все заработало с первого раза! Подозрительно как-то, протестирую еще разок :)).

Comment: Я сам когда делал аналогичное дюже удивлялся)))